# Incompatible element type String for collection of SOBJECT:Call2_vod__c

Tags: apex, batch, list, set

I have the below code where the Set and list is of same type Call2_vod__c , a custom object in salesforce but still throws subject error in that line. Can some one help me here?

Apex class:

```
global class AckCallUpdatenew implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like \'%Sample%\' and Status_vod__c = \'Submitted_vod\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) {

    List<Call2_vod__c> AckCall= 
            [SELECT  Ack_For_Call_abv__c  
                      FROM Call2_vod__c
                     where  recordtype.Name like '%Acknowledge%'];

   // Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,Call2_vod__c>(AckCall)).keySet();    
    Set<Call2_vod__c> s1 = new Set<Call2_vod__c>(AckCall);             
         for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
         {
           If(!s1.contains(a.Name))
           {
                  if(a.ESR_Call__c==false && a.Call_Date_vod__c+90<date.today())
                   {
                    a.Unlock_vod__c=true;
                    a.ESR_Call__c=true;
                    }


           }
              update a;
         }
             }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set<Call2_Vod__c>` can't lookup a String (which you're trying to do by a.Name). You'd have to make a map based like `Map<String, Call2_Vod__c>`, or a `Set<String>` of names that exist.

You'll probably want to change your execute method to look like this:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
for(Call2_Vod__c record:scope) {
    names.add(record.Name);
}
for(Call2_Vod__c record:[SELECT Name FROM Call2_Vod__c WHERE recordType.Name LIKE '%Acknowledge%') {
    names.remove(record.Name);
}
for(Call2_Vod__c record:scope) {
    if(!names.contains(record.Name) && !record.ESR_Call__c && record.Call_Date_Vod__c.addDays(90)<System.Today()) {
        record.Unlock_Vod__c = record.ESR_Call__c = true;
    }
}
update scope;
```

While I don't know exactly what your intent is, this should probably get you closer to where you want to be.

Also note how I moved the update outside the loop. You shouldn't perform DML operations in a loop, even in a batch process, to avoid errors.